# one JB java project to rule them all

Tags: java, dependencies, javabeans

I'm new to Java so sorry if I don't use the right terms. I've got a few java projects on my NetBeans 7.3. One is a Java project (with a main and a console output) and 3 are Web projects (creating and running web servers). How do I define one project that contains all those and compiling it compiles the all the 4 projects ?

Comment: add them as libraries

Answer (score 1):

As them to the main project like this, right click in main project -> properties

[image: netbeans adding project]

Comment: I can't do that. Trying to add the web server apps as projects to the other projects (tried with the java project and with other web server projects) gets me a error message: "this project cannot be added because it does not produce a JAr file using an Ant script"